# refer different object in the template

Tags: ember.js

I am in the initial phases of learning ember.js. I was trying out an application and am stuck while referencing another object from an object present in the controller..

```
  {{#each employee in controller}}
  <tr>
  <td class="span2"><input type="checkbox" style="margin-left : 110px;"/></td>
  <td class="span2">{{#linkTo 'employee' employee}}{{employee.empId}}{{/linkTo}}</td>
  <td class="span2">{{employee.name}}</td>
  <td class="span2">{{employee.age}}</td>
  <td class="span2">{{employee.dob}}</td>
  <td class="span2">{{employee.gender}}</td>
  <td class="span2">{{employee.doj}}</td>
  <td class="span2">{{#linkTo 'employee' employee}}{{employee.mgrId}}{{/linkTo}}</td>
  <td class="span2">{{employee.package}}</td>
  <td class="span2">{{employee.address}}</td>
  <td class="span2">{{employee.phone}}</td>
  <td> <button {{action "deleteEmployee" employee}}> Delete </button></td>
  {{/each}}
```

Here I was trying to fetch the details of the manager using the id..

code for index route is :

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('employee',{
        path: "/employee/:employee_id"},
        function() {
            this.route('edit');
        }
    );
    this.route('allEmployees');
  // put your routes here
});

App.AllEmployeesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        //console.log(param.patient_id);
        var employees = [];
        for(var employee_id in App.Employees)
        {
            employees.push(App.Employees[employee_id])
        }
        return employees;

    }
});


App.Employee = Ember.Object.extend({
        "empId":null,
        "name":null,
        "age":null,
        "dob":null,
        "gender":null,
        "doj":null,
        "mgrId":null,
        "package":null,
        "address":null,
        "phone":null
    });

// Code for event handling
App.AllEmployeesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
        deleteEmployee:function(employee){
            var employees = this.get('model');
            for(var i=0; i<employees.length;i++)
            {
                if(employees[i].empId === employee.empId)

                employees.removeAt(i);

            }

        console.log("deleting "+employee.empId);
        }   
    }
);
```

so how is this done in ember?

EDIT :

JSON Record structure :

```
App.Employees = {
    "1" : App.Employee.create({
        "id" : "1",
        "empId" : "emp1",
        "name" : "Employee 1", 
        "age" : "23",
        "dob" : "17/12/89",
        "gender" : "male",
        "doj" : "9/1/12",
        "mgrId" : "emp6",
        "package" : "300000",
        "address" : "address 1",
        "phone" : "9999999999"
    }),
    "2" : App.Employee.create({
        "id" : "2",
        "empId" : "emp2",
        "name" : "Employee 2", 
        "age" : "24",
        "dob" : "18/1/90",
        "gender" : "female",
        "doj" : "20/2/13",
        "mgrId" : "",
        "package" : "350000",
        "address" : "address 2",
        "phone" : "9437543985"

    }),
    "3" : App.Employee.create({
        "id" : "3",
        "empId" : "emp3",
        "name" : "Employee 3", 
        "age" : "25",
        "dob" : "19/2/91",
        "gender" : "male",
        "doj" : "12/12/11",
        "mgrId" : "emp2",
        "package" : "300000",
        "address" : "address 3",
        "phone" : "3454395943"
    }), }
```

Comment: can you post your controllers where you want to establish the references?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `needs` API to access other controllers from your specific controller.

```
needs: 'manager',
managerBinding: 'controllers.manager'
```

From there, if `manager` is the object you want, you can reference it via `this.get('manager')` in controller and as `manager` in the corresponding template.

Comment: darshan thanks for your answer. Actually I have put all the employee records as json objects with mgrId as a field. and on the UI I am presenting it as a link.. so when a user clicks on the mgrId. he should be directed to the managers record, which is also an employee.. so want to load that particular record on the basis of the id.. I am adding the record structure in the question..

Comment: It doesn't look like `manager` is a parent route of `employee`. In that case you need to load this record. A good place would be on the route's `setupController`. Generally it is a good idea to sideload/embed these kind of dependent records, so that you don't have to be explicitly loaded later.